# Meaningful sentence generation from words which are classified as per parts of speech

Tags: python, nlp, nlg

I am working on Natural Language Generation project.
I've created bag of words from paragraph,like nouns,verbs,adjectives.etc
and I am trying to generate sentence of pattern Subject+verb+object.

Example:

- Noun: Elizabeth, Dog, Eiffel Tower, Bike
- Verb: Sings, barks, shines
- Current output: Elizabeth shines,  Eiffel Tower barks,  Bike sings ..etc
- Expected pairs: Elizabeth sings, Dog barks, Eiffel Tower shines, Bike shines

Subject and verbs must have a relation which will create a meaningful sentence.Is there any way to establish relation between nouns and probable verbs  to generate subject+verb pattern?

Also If we have verbs then to find probable objects using input corpus to generate new meaningful sentences?

Example:

- Verb: riding, reading
- Objects: horse,bike, books,novels.
- Expected pairs: riding horse,riding bike, reading books,reading novels.

Answer (score 2):

Let's think about it this way. There are certain acts like barking and singing that could only be done by animate beings, thus a bike,
an inanimate object, cannot sing. Also, barking is done by an animal, i.e, a human cannot be the one who does the act of barking.
So let's define certain features for each one of our constituents. For instance:

```
eli = {'CAT': 'N', 'ORTH': 'Elizabeth', 'FEAT':'human'}
dog = {'CAT': 'N', 'ORTH': 'dog', 'FEAT':'animal'}
eiffel = {'CAT': 'N', 'ORTH': 'Eiffel Tower', 'FEAT':'inanimate'}
bike = {'CAT': 'N', 'ORTH': 'Bike', 'FEAT':'inanimate'}

nouns = [eli, dog, eiffel, bike]

sings = {'CAT': 'V', 'ORTH': 'sings', 'FEAT':'human'}
barks = {'CAT': 'V', 'ORTH': 'barks', 'FEAT':'animal'}
shines = {'CAT': 'V', 'ORTH': 'shines', 'FEAT':'inanimate'}

verbs = [sings, barks, shines]

# Our sentence pattern is: noun + verb + noun

for n in nouns:
    for v in verbs:
        if n['FEAT'] == v['FEAT']:
            print('{} {}'.format(n['ORTH'], v['ORTH']))
```

When you run this you get:

```
>>> 
Elizabeth sings
dog barks
Eiffel Tower shines
Bike shines
>>>
```

Same goes for pairing verbs with suitable objects. You simply have to assign proper features to your pairs.

Answer (score 1):

See the set of works under the name of ["narrative schemas"](http://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/nchamber/data/schemas/acl09/) by Nate Chambers. He does what you want.

[This](http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~khashab2/files/2015_Winograd_naacl/NAACL2015.pdf) might be relevant as well.